# Axapta 2009 X++ Reverse only selected PackingSlip

Tags: axapta, x++

How to modify X++ AX so it will correctly pick the right packing (if I know the PackingslipId)?

For example, I'm doing 3 times packing for an item with different quantity like this:
1. Qty=50
2. Qty=20
3. Qty=30

Then I want to reverse Packing #2 (Qty 20), currently AX will deduct Packing #1 and that is wrong and not what I wanted, because I what I did is reversing packing #2 and I do not want to deduct from any other packing slip at all.

Currently there is two solution I know to reverse packingslip:
1. Use (-) Deliver Now field on SO then repacking using Deliver Now, problem is with this approach, AX will deduct the first packing which is 50-20=30, well there is no way AX will know what packingslip actually I want to deduct from (nowhere to put packingslipid to deduct from)
2. Invoice and credit note the packingslip which I want to reverse, this way AX will correctly deduct from the correct packingslip, problem is the steps is too much and need to be invoiced and credit noted??

So is there a way which user may only select a packingslipid which want to be reversed then AX will reverse that packingslip? as simple as this will help alot for user.

Thank you

Comment: How do you reverse packing no. 2? Please provide the steps to do that. I can see how to reverse a picking slip, but not a packing slip

Comment: Consider improving your question to get the help you need.

Comment: I agree. There are several ways in which to do what you are discussing. Perhaps this is not even a code issue. This sounds like a process issue.

Comment: You could always try asking your question at the [Ax Dynamics Community](https://community.dynamics.com/product/ax/f/33.aspx).

Comment: @ian_scho, I'm asking there already, but got no answer, though in here I will... Anyway in here I feel people more responsive to help me :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no standard way of doing this.

Comment: OK I'm pretty sure now, standard AX cannot do what I want, though I hope someone will help me to modif it using X++