# Axapta 2009 X++ download text file from a website

Tags: axapta, dynamics-ax-2009, x++

I would like to download a text file from a website, given I know the URL of it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a few examples in [Axaptapedia.com, loading Web Documents](http://www.axaptapedia.com/Load_Web_Documents).  The examples use the Microsoft .NET Framework.  The code below is from Axaptapedia:

```
public static void TEST_DownloadString (Args _args)
{
    System.Net.WebClient webClient = new System.Net.WebClient();
    ;
    info(webClient.DownloadString('http://axaptapedia.com'));
}
```

Comment: you are great Jan B. thank you anyway could you please also help my other question on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8121140/axapta-2009-x-reverse-only-selected-packingslip