# Parse XML from URL

Tags: xml, web-services, axapta, x++

I'm trying to use Google Maps to calculate the distance between 2 points.I have the following url :

`http://maps.google.com/maps/api/directions/xml?language=fr&origin="+parm1+"&destination="+parm2+"&sensor=false`

I'm quite a newbie in managing xml with x++ so how can I get the xml code returned by my url and parse it to extract the data I need (distance node values).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, see this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8257066/4509).

Then have a look here:

http://www.axaptapedia.com/Webservice

http://www.axaptapedia.com/XML

How you do it may in part depend on you AX version.

Comment: Thank you very much, the answer was exactly what I was looking for, I also read the axaptapedia chapter on xml/WebServices, I'm using AX 2009

Answer (score 0):

I was playing around with the two links Jan posted and got something you should be able to work with.  I noticed some strangeness with the "node.hasChildNodes()", where it would say there was a child, when there was none, but it had available text.  See if you can work with this.

```
static void XML_WebService_CodeGoogle(Args _args)
{
    System.Net.WebClient webClient = new System.Net.WebClient();
    str google = "http://maps.google.com/maps/api/directions/xml?language=en&origin=85251&destination=46220&sensor=false";
    str retVal = webClient.DownloadString(google);
    XMLDocument doc=XMLDocument::newXml(retVal);


    XmlNamedNodemap     attributes;
    XmlElement          root = doc.root();
    XmlNode             node = root.firstChild();

    str numOfSpaces(int _depth)
    {
        str spc;
        int n;
        ;

        for (n=0; n<=_depth; n++)
            spc+='  ';

        return spc;
    }

    void dig(XmlNode _node, int _depth = 0)
    {
        XmlNode sib;
        ;

        if (_node == null)
            return;

        if (_node.hasChildNodes())
            info(strfmt("%1%2", numOfSpaces(_depth), _node.name()));

        if (_node.hasChildNodes())
            dig(_node.firstChild(), (_depth+1));
        else
            info(strfmt("%1[%2]", numOfSpaces(_depth), _node.innerText()));

        sib = _node.nextSibling();

        if (sib)
            dig(sib);
    }
    ;

    dig(node);
}
```

Comment: It uses recursion to iterate over the XML.  I haven't tested if it works 100% correctly yet.  I actually think the last part where it iterates over siblings might be wrong, but it was throwing it into an infinite loop and I just didn't have time to keep playing with it.